# Pentaho | Tools-> Wizard-> Copy Tables

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to copy tables from one database to another database.
I have gone through google and find out that we can do this with Wizard option of Tools Menu in Spoon.

Currently I am trying to copy just one table from one database into another table.

My table has just 130 000 records and it took 10 mins to copy table.
Can we improve this loading timings? I mean just to copy 100k records, it should not take more than 10 seconds.

Comment: you need to add a lot more information.  What is the source db? is it over a network?  Are you copying ALL the records or just some?  What is the target db..  What version of PDI, and what operating system

Comment: source db:- mysql
all records copying/

Comment: target db is also mysql

Comment: Pentaho version 6.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Try the mysql bulk loader - note: that is linux only

OR

2. fix the batch size:

http://julienhofstede.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/increase-mysql-output-to-80k-rowssecond.html

You'll get massive improvements that way.